# Using polar coordinates to evaluate a double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I was asked to evaluate the following double integral, using polar coordinates:
$$\int_0^{2a} \int_0^{\sqrt{2ax - x^2}} x^2 + y^2 dydx$$
We know that $dA = rdrd\theta$ and $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$. Also, I found the upper bound to be $2acos\theta$, by squaring both sides of $y = \sqrt{2ax - x^2}$ and substituting $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ and $x = rcos\theta$. So the integral becomes
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2acos\theta} r^3 drd\theta$$
Integrating the inside integral with respect to $dr$
$$\int_0^{2acos\theta} r^3 dr = \frac{r^4}{4}\Bigg\vert_0^{2acos\theta}$$
$$ = \frac{(2acos\theta)^4}4 $$
$$ = 4a^4cos^4\theta $$
If we place back $4a^4cos^4$ on the double integral, we get $4a^4\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} cos^4 d\theta$; for this one, I used wolphram|alpha and it returned me $\frac{3\pi a^4}{2}$, which is weird, since the textbook answer for this particular exercise is $\frac{3\pi a^4}4$.

It's just a factor of one half, but still;
I wonder if there is something wrong with my process, I'm guessing I could be using a wrong domain when transforming from cartesian coordinates to polar, but I can't spot the error.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should have $0\le\theta\le\pi/2$ from [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v25bssickr) graph. This loses a factor of $2$.

Comment: Since $y\geq 0$, the domain of $\theta$ is $[0,\frac\pi2)$.